# How does QTable behave for last edited cell?

Tags: qt, qt3

When I edit a cell of `QTable` inside `QDialog` and press 'ok' button of `QDialog`, the cell's value is nothing (if it was nothing before edit). So, in the slot for `OkButton` (i.e. `OkButton->clicked()`), I access value of every cell in the `QTable`. However, the last edited cell is not yet filled. Strange!

Note, if I click somewhere else within `QTable` before pressing `OkButton`, it works fine, that is, I can then see the last edited cell's value with `QTable->text(row, col)`.
 Could someone please help me in understanding what is missing here that results in this behavior?

Another interesting behavior: In the slot for `OkButton`, since, I don't find a value, I call `QMessageBox::information()`. During debugging, when I say 'next' (in gdb) on this statement, the `valueChanged()` signal is emitted (I am catching it and printing). I don't understand why is this signal so delayed; why did `QTable` did not record the changed value earlier??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the possible solution is to trigger endEdit() somehow. The method that I employed is to have following code from the handler/slot of OkButton.

```
mTable->setEnabled(false);  // wil trigger endEdit()
mTable->setEnabled(true);
// Access mTable's cells now
QString cell_content = mTable->text(i, j);
```

This code did solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a qt3 available, but I had a similar problem with QTableView in Qt 4.6.

You might have to call the function [endEdit(row,col,true,false)](http://doc.trolltech.com/3.3/qtable.html#endEdit):

> void QTable::endEdit ( int row, int col, bool accept, bool replace ) [virtual protected]
>
> This function is called when in-place editing of the cell at row, col
>   is requested to stop. If the cell is not being edited or accept is
>   FALSE the function returns and the cell's contents are left unchanged.
>
> If accept is TRUE the content of the editor must be transferred to the
>   relevant cell. If replace is TRUE the current content of this cell
>   should be replaced by the content of the editor (this means removing
>   the current QTableItem of the cell and creating a new one for the
>   cell). Otherwise (if possible) the content of the editor should just
>   be set to the existing QTableItem of this cell.

I had to call [commitData()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qabstractitemview.html#id-830263e2-d393-4d45-b0ce-19f8676e1b2a) in my case and this seems to do the same job.

Comment: The issue is that there is not good place to call endEdit from. I did not want to subclass just for this either (which might not have helped either). I have found a different workaround, which is quite good. I have given it below as answer.